# How to install other languages on Libreoffice Snap

Tags: libreoffice, snap, language-support

As you can imagine, I am trying to find a way to **add** Greek *(or any other language)* on LibreOffice (6.0.2) **Snap**.

Currently the available languages for **User Interface** are 9 basic languages only.

Any thoughts?

Currently running Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create a LibreOffice extension (`.oxt`) file from a language pack, and than install it.
In my case I just made a hungarian language extension with the following steps:

1. Download you official language pack, it is usually in a `.tar.gz` file. (eg: `LibreOffice_7.1.2_Linux_x86-64_deb_langpack_hu.tar.gz`)
2. Open it with an archive file manager
3. Search for a file with a name that has dict in it (eg.: `libreoffice7.1-dict-hu_7.1.2.2-2_amd64.deb` )
4. Open it with an archive file manager
5. Open `data.tar.xz`
6. Navigate to the `/./opt/libreoffice7.1/share/extensions/` folder in it
7. You will have a folder in it. In my case: `dict-hu` (because it is a Hungarian dictionary)
8. Extract all files from the `dict-hu` (but not the directory itself!) folder to a folder in your home directory. It does not matter where exactly.
9. Select all files you just extracted
10. Compress all of them to a `.zip` file
11. Replace the `.zip` filename extension with `.oxt`
12. Your LibreOffice extension is done. Install it in LibreOffice Writer.
13. Restart LibreOffice.
14. Set your default document language in LibreOffice Writer to the desired one.

I hope they fix this problem properly in the future so you wont need this workaround.

Comment: works great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Manually repacking snap or injecting [*-el* localization packages](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/?type=deb-x86_64&version=6.0.2&lang=el) seems to be difficult.

So the better option is to drop Snap, and use LibreOffice from [“LibreOffice Packaging” team PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then install Greek packages with

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-l10n-el libreoffice-help-el
```

Answer (score 0):

For LibreOffice 7.1 on Ubuntu 20, download your language pack via https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Language/Support

You get an `*.oxt` file from Apache OpenOffice extensions

Open the file with LibreOffice 7.1 and that's it.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20. There is a version 20.04 and a 20.10